# matlab application error for creating the account

Tags: matlab

I created a matlab application.One of the GUI's(sub GUI) is for creating an account.In this code there is a function which calls other files for creating the account. MY question is "Will this create a problem in creating the account?". Because i'm getting error(sound). Can't really understand what the problem is.This code is not creating the account which i needed.(When it is in standalone ). the same code is workng normally.

Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
P1='1212'
P2='1212'

if p1==p2

  mval=questdlg('Are you Sure?','Please Make Sure you have entered valid password')

if mval=='Yes'
n=randi([1,10]);
ipath='Initial\';
fname=strcat(ipath,num2str(n),'.png');
idata=imread(fname,'PNG');
dname=strcat('Database\',us,'.png');
idata=uint8(idata);
imwrite(idata,dname);
createuser(dname,p1);
else
close(questdlg);
end
```

createuser(dname,p1); is the fucntion that calls many other files for  creating the account.

Comment: So what exactly is the error?  Where is it happening?

Comment: This code is not creating the account which i needed.(When it is in standalone ). the same code is workng normally.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't understand what your problem is.  What **exactly** happens when you create an account?  Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: BTW, doing `if mval == 'Yes'` is not comparing strings.  Do `if strcmpi(mval, 'Yes')`.  Same with `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: @rayryeng. I Cannot upload the image for not having the required reputations. This code when run in the matlab window gives me a GUI containing (Username ,Password, Reenter password and submit button). As i enter credentials and click 'submit ' button it creates an account. The same is not working when i turned this into application. (When i click on submit button its giving error sound, account is not created)

Comment: Upload the image on a public sharing website, and I will put it in your post.

Comment: Please put in the **exact** error you are experiencing and where it's happening in your code as well.  In the MATLAB command prompt, you will see a whole bunch of text in **red**.  What does that text say?  **Put that into your question**.  I can't keep asking you this because I think I've made myself pretty clear.  If I can't figure out where exactly in the code the error is happening (mainly because you're not telling me where), I'm sorry to say that I'm going to give up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I uploaded the image in my blog http://artefactz.blogspot.in/ pls check it you may get idea.

Comment: That's only your GUI, which isn't my concern right now.  My concern is the **exact** error and **where** it's happening in your code.  This is the **third** time I've had to ask.  I'm giving up.  Good luck!

Comment: Run your exe from a dos prompt, that way you will see the error message that is thrown when you push the button in the compiled app.

Comment: Its showing that cannot have write permission (dname=strcat('Database\',us,'.png'); %%%%  This might be because i did not give entire path..

Comment: @Frank - Well there you go.  Change the code so that you're writing to a directory where you **do** have permission.